# What strategy should I use to unit test reading a file in ruby (rspec)?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, stubbing

I've got a ruby method which processes a very large file line-by-line (ie I cannot load the file into memory) like the following:

```
def process_file
   file = File.new(@@data_file, "r") 
     while (line = file.gets)
       { do something with the line } ...
     end
   file.close

   return "upload complete"
end
```

As per best practices, I do not want this this method to have any reliance on the filesystem.  I've used stubs before, but I'm not sure how I would go about using it here.  I would imagine I would use something equivalent to:

```
file = File.stub!(:new).and_return({something})
```

I'm just not sure what {something} is.

I am using rspect and Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a unit test is called for here.  Are you afraid that, somehow, creating files/closing files is going to be broken in some future version of Ruby?  It's not, don't worry.

Let the Ruby devs worry about unit testing their platform specific file IO routines.  You should worry about unit testing your *algorithms*, and specifically those algorithms which are critical and complex (i.e., prone to breakage if you're not careful).

That said, you should probably just pass a block to the constructor.  This ensures that the file will be closed for you when the block exits and is more idiomatic.

```
File.open(some_file_path, 'w+') do |file|
  file.puts('content')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What I'm trying to test is not the file i/o.  What I'm trying to test is what happens to the individual records in the file (ie .. in the loop).  I can stub/mock what is in the files easily.  What I am having trouble stubbing/mocking is the opening/closing of the file itself.

Comment: @Agazoom: Ok, well how about taking the file out of the equation entirely?  The file operations work like any other IO routine.  Pass in a mocked input stream to the algorithm and verify that the output is correct.  It doesn't have to actually be a file object, it just needs to have the same interface.

Comment: Any pointers on where I can look up something like that?  I'm new to ruby so any source you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: Regarding the code snippet above, I assume that means that the entire file is loaded into memory, is it not?

Comment: Actually, that is not the case.   The file is not loaded into memory and I can certainly stub out 'File.open'.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if you call proper methods, at least the `close()` after. I think that's the most often error with i/o.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [MockFS](http://mockfs.rubyforge.org/), which mocks out the operation of the filesystem.